# How to fix timeout while parsing a JSON feed into a Google Sheet?

Tags: python, json, request, timeout, gspread

I'm pretty new to this and it's taken me days to get this far, the script I have now that pushes a JSON feed into a Google Sheet works for my test link, but times out when used with the URL I actually need to pull from.

I can confirm the real URL works, and I have access - I'm able to print to terminal no problem.

It has sensitive info, so I'm unable to share - I've looked into proxies, and URIs, but haven't really been able how to figure any of it out with my code.

```
# import urllib library
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

import gspread
import requests

gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('1-1aiGMn2yUWRlh_jnIebcMNs-6phzUNxkktAFH7uY9o')
worksheet = sh.sheet1


url = 'URL LINK GOES HERE'


# store the response of URL
response = urlopen(Request(url, headers={"User-Agent": ""}))
r = requests.get("URL LINK GOES HERE",
                 proxies={"http": "http://61.233.25.166:80"})

# storing the JSON response
# from url in data
data_json = json.loads(response.read())

# print the json response
# print(data_json)
result = []
for key in data_json:
    result.append([key, data_json[key] if not isinstance(
        data_json[key], list) else ",".join(map(str, data_json[key]))])
worksheet.update('a1', result)

# proxies///uris///url 100% works
```

Does anyone have advice on how I could avoid the timeout? Full error is below:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\AMadle\NBA-JSON-Fetch\2PrintToSheetTimeoutTesting.py", line 17, in <module>
    response = urlopen(Request(url, headers={"User-Agent": ""}))
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\urllib\request.py", line 519, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\urllib\request.py", line 536, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1391, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1351, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

Comment: What are you printing to the terminal? How exactly did you confirm your URL works?

Comment: I'm printing a link for work that I'm unable to share, but I confirmed it works by printing the same API to terminal. It gets a timeout when I try to push to Sheets @koolkoda

Answer (score 3):

Here's a couple of things:

1. Is this the full code? I know you said it has sensitive information, but could you simply censor it instead of deleting entirely,
2. The provided logs show a URLError. How do you know it's a timeout exception. If it was a timeout, wouldn't it raise a TimeoutException?
3. Are you trying to read or write data? Saying pushing or pulling interchangeably makes no sense.

Comment: I am beyond sorry, I shared the incorrect script.  Have tried a million different ways, I've updated my question with the CORRECT script.  The previous error was fixed, then ran into this  "a connection attempt failed...". I am trying to write data to the sheet. My apologies!!!

Comment: No worries! Glad you figured it out! Sorry if I sounded a bit harsh.

Comment: Appreciate it @ShadowProgrammer - unfortunately I've yet to figure out a fix for my main issue (which was the timeout), but at least I have the correct script here now.  Appreciate you catching my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to test your code I could make a guess. Looks like there is no connection to server. Since you are saying that url works (how do you try it btw?) then it could be that specifically the way urlopen connects is not working. As per my understanding urllib docs says this (https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.ProxyHandler):

> In addition, if proxy settings are detected (for example, when a
> *_proxy environment variable like http_proxy is set), ProxyHandler is default installed and makes sure the requests are handled through the
> proxy.
>
> If no proxy environment variables are set, then in a Windows
> environment proxy settings are obtained from the registry’s Internet
> Settings section, and in a Mac OS X environment proxy information is
> retrieved from the OS X System Configuration Framework.
>
> To disable autodetected proxy pass an empty dictionary.

What is your OS btw?

You could check your proxy settings with `urllib.request.getproxies()`

And you could try change the proxy settings. I am unfortunately not sure of exact syntaxis with urllib library (better use requests btw) but another guess smth like this:

```
req = Request(url, headers={"User-Agent": ""})
req.set_proxy("", "http") # empty proxy for http
response = urlopen(req)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the request fails, it seems the gspread is not causing the issue. First of I’d suggest using the included ‘json()’ function from the request. Furthermore, I’d coalesce the one-item-or-a-list to always be a list and always use str join for clarity.

If you only sometimes get timeouts try figuring out which records are affected. Perhaps your requesting a really large data set via a proxy.

Or perhaps the proxy is flaky. Perhaps a retry is worth a try?